# Making MonoDevelop-Unity behave more like Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm trying to get MonoDevelop-Unity to behave more like Visual Studio.  I have compiled a list of issues regarding this.

1) Errors are never automatically shown on the Error Pane at the bottom of the main window.  I have to tab to Unity to see them.

[image]

2) The document is never automatically formatted in real-time when typing.  I would like the line to be properly spaced when appending it with a ';', the same goes for '}'.

I have played around with Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Indentation and Source Code settings but to no avail.

3) When hitting run I have to go into Unity and hit run rather than Unity being run automatically

Can anyone please tell me how these issues can be resolved?

Comment: what version of monodevelop are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.1

Comment: great, then I recommend you to test 4.2.x, and if you still find any of the issues above with this new version, then file each of them in a bug report here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Will the new version work with Unity?

Comment: @user1423893 No, it won't, it's not a matter of simply upgrading, you'll have to hack to do this.

Comment: as far as I've heard, it's not that complicated: you can install a Unity addin via the Addin Manager menu

Comment: Can you please point me to a website that explains how this can be done?  My searches have resulted in hack attempts only.

Comment: Point "1)" does always work, are you seeing your scripts in the solution view? if not, reinstall unity.

Comment: All the scripts associated with the project can be seen in the solution view.

Comment: For your first issue you can use the F7(build button). Will build your unity solution without booting unity. Errors and warnings will be pushed to the error/warning pane. But will also be shown in-line

Comment: That helps, thank you.  However, it would be better if they showed up automatically.

Comment: While not strictly an answer to your problem, Microsoft have now acquired UnityVS company SyntaxTree, and are offering UnityVS for free for Visual Studio 2010-2013 Professional or higher.

You can download it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/07/29/visual-studio-tools-for-unity-1-9.aspx, or get it from the Visual Studio Extensions Gallery.